# Where can I read about ContentManager.Query() in Orchard?

Tags: documentation, orchardcms

I hate to ask questions like these, but where can I learn about this particular part of the Orchard API?

The documentation doesn't go into half as much detail as it should/could so would be very grateful if somebody could point me in the right direction of an example/usage explanation of `Query()` and it's overloads. I can't accurately form a query without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Training Demo module has a lot of examples: https://orchardtrainingdemo.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Controllers/ContentsAdminController.cs

Beware though: https://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/20131